# ROS installation on Mac with Homebrew--bootstrapping issues?

Tags: macos, homebrew, rosinstall, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to install ROS on my MacBook Pro (running Mac OS X 10.7.3).  I have followed everything in the installation instructions here (http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew), but at the very end of the Desktop-Full Install, I get this:

```
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /Users/lauraS/ros
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
/bin/bash: rosmake: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.6.11', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.6.11-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 11, in <module>
    
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 213, in rosinstall_main
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 88, in cmd_generate_ros_files
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 504, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/lauraS/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

And if I try to run the next step, `source ~/ros/setup.bash`, I get:

```
    sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros
```

I'm kind of new at this and am not actually sure what bootstrapping is, and I've no idea how to go about getting things installed properly from this point.  Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

**Update:** After taking tmf's suggestions, I think the installer has gotten further than it got before, but now after `rosinstall` installs `robot_model_tutorials`, I get this:

```
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /Users/lauraS/ros
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
```

and then it hangs until I ctrl-c it.  For the record, I have tried running the `rosinstall` command both on a ~/ros folder that has all of the files from the previous install attempts in it and on a ~/ros folder that I emptied myself.  I'd appreciate any ideas of how to get the installation to finish!  Thanks!

**Update 2:**  In case it helps, here is what shows up on my Terminal after I push ctrl-c when the install hangs at `Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.`:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lauraS/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 55, in <module>
    if not assert_rospack_built():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.6.11', 'rosinstall')
  File "/Users/lauraS/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 45, in assert_rospack_built
    if subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) :
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1243, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 471, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.6.11-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 11, in <module>
    
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 213, in rosinstall_main
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 88, in cmd_generate_ros_files
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 499, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1243, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 471, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Does that information happen to help anyone shed some light on what might be keeping the installation from continuing?  From what I've seen on other questions people have asked, my installation is on the right track but just can't continue past detecting the other bootstrapper for some reason.  I'd appreciate any ideas!  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30339/ros-installation-on-mac-with-homebrew--bootstrapping-issues?/) by [lauras](https://answers.ros.org/users/2040/lauras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lauras](https://answers.ros.org/users/2040/lauras/) on 2012-08-08**:
UPDATE: Sorry for the lack of responses--I switched to my Ubuntu VM for this project.  But when the project is over, I'll try installing ROS on my Mac again.  Thanks for the help (and the bug fix)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug in rosinstall.  It's fixed in 0.6.12.  [Ticket](https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/trac/ticket/33)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi lauras,

I'm also new to homebrew, ros and the way the install scripts usually should be patched, but I solved like this:

- make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` (Lion: `/etc/paths`)
- install gnu-sed with homebrew (`brew install gnu-sed`)
- link /usr/local/bin/sed to /usr/local/bin/gsed (`ln -s /usr/local/bin/gsed /usr/local/bin/sed`)

That worked for me...

---

Originally posted by [tmf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2043/tmf/) with karma: 51 on 2012-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lauras](https://answers.ros.org/users/2040/lauras/) on 2012-03-24**:
Hi tmf, thanks for the answer!  I think my installation has gotten further than it was before, but still no dice.  I'm updating my original question; if you or anyone else has ideas of how to proceed from here, I'd love to hear.  Thanks!

**Comment by [tmf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2043/tmf/) on 2012-03-24**:
Hi lauras,
What was the first error encountered before it hangs after robot_model_tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a hint that the ROS Installation on OSX can hang for log4cxx and a fresh install of the Apple Java thingy:
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/electric(2f)Installation(2f)OSX(2f)Homebrew.html 3.2 Log4cxx Installation Hangs

After that I installed log4cxx manually with brew:

```
brew install -v log4cxx
```

When restarting the ROS installation, I had also some error on ros_comm-rosconsole and applied the patch provided in:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/attachment/ticket/3626/ros_comm-rosconsole-llvm.patch

After that the installation worked on a "clean" Lion install with the new XCode 4.3 compiler tools.

Perhaps that helps....

---

Originally posted by [tmf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2043/tmf/) with karma: 51 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lauras](https://answers.ros.org/users/2040/lauras/) on 2012-03-25**:
Thanks for the info!  I tried the log4cxx installation, but the installer still hangs at "Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too." Could you provide more info about how to install the patch you recommended? I don't want to break things by putting the patch in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same problem here. Seems that rosmake that is hanging. If I run "rosmake" it hangs, independently of which arguments I pass.

UPDATE: Seems that the problem is that ausparc.com is offline (here it is not responding). Just use rosmake --no-rosdep

---

Originally posted by [gbuzogany](https://answers.ros.org/users/2198/gbuzogany/) with karma: 11 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run Brew doctor
This told me that my xcode command tools were not installed and my path was not correct.

---

Originally posted by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) with karma: 46 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-03**:
They are not installed automatically now